# Put google places pac-container inside div?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am using the google places autocomplete api and when I initialize the auto complete element `autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('#google_places_ac')[0], {})` it appends the `.pac-container` to the body.

I have a div that is scrollable that this content is in so what happens is the `.pac-container` is positioned absolute and when the div scrolls it does not scroll with it.

Is there any way I can get the `.pac-container` to be inserted inside of my div and not at the end of the body?

Answer (score 9):

It's not a perfect solution but it the best I could find

```
var addressInputElement = $('#yourInputElementId');
addressInputElement.on('focus', function () {
  var pacContainer = $('.pac-container');
  $(addressInputElement.parent()).append(pacContainer);
})
```

you might be needed to change some css as well

```
.pac-container {  
  z-index: 9999999 !important;  
  top: 32px !important;   //your input height
  left: 0 !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to blur the input field on scrolling.

```
$('insert-scrolling-container').on('scroll', function() {
    $('#google_places_ac').blur();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put google places **pac-container** inside div check this solution

```
function initAutocomplete() {
      //....codes...
       //....add this code just before close function...
    setTimeout(function(){ 
                $(".pac-container").prependTo("#mapMoveHere");
            }, 300);
}
```

https://codepen.io/gmkhussain/pen/qPpryg

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this whilst trying to find a solution to the same problem.

I ended up doing it using the **MooTools** JavaScript framework.

Hope this helps anyone who comes across the same problem.

```
    // Start Address is the address form input field
    // Add a focus to delay this being run
    $('StartAddress').addEvent('focus', function()
    {
         // Make sure the new location of the .pac-container doesn't already contain it
         if($$('.route-form fieldset .pac-container').length == 0)
         {
              // Use adopt() to move the .pac-container to its new location
              // This method will keep all relations between the element and Google Maps
              $$('.route-form fieldset')[0].adopt($$('.pac-container'));
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution but it the best I could find

```
var addressInputElement = $('#yourInputElementId');
addressInputElement.on('focus', function () {
  var pacContainer = $('.pac-container');
  $(addressInputElement.parent()).append(pacContainer);
})
```

you might be needed to change some css as well

```
.pac-container {  
  z-index: 9999999 !important;  
  top: 32px !important;   //your input height
  left: 0 !important; 
}
```

get this comment from first i cant check useful but i will repeat it